git log command not give full commits of all branches
I wanted to see all commits of all branches. so i tried git log , but it gave some results and struck as in below screenshot :


Press the space bar to see more.

@Jos thanks , please post it as an answer

Your git log command pipes its output to a program with the generic name pager. On my (plain vanilla) system this is /usr/bin/pager, which is itself an alias for /usr/bin/less. less has many keyboard shortcuts, which it will tell you about by entering man less. The most important of these is the space bar, which scrolls the text forward one window.
Another very useful one is q which exits less and returns you to the command prompt. Up and down arrows, PageUp and PageDown also work.
If you don't like the default pager, you can replace it with
git config --global core.pager "my_favourite_pager".
